# Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Decimal

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

Im importing a csv to my sql server table using the following code

```
SqlCommand nonqueryCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
nonqueryCommand.CommandText = 
                 "INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES(@num1, @num2,@num3,@num4)";

nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@num1",SqlDbType.Decimal);
nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@num2", SqlDbType.Decimal);
nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@num3", SqlDbType.Decimal);
nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@num4", SqlDbType.Decimal);

nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@num1"].Value = crntRecord[0];
nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@num2"].Value = crntRecord[1];
nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@num3"].Value =crntRecord[3];
nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@num4"].Value = crntRecord[4];

nonqueryCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

where the parameter 3 and 4 are of type decimal(9,6) in the DDL when i execute the code at `ExecuteNonQuery` i get the following exception

> Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Decimal.

please help me find out the problem tnx.

EDIT

the value in the crntRecord[3] looks like

[image]

Comment: What are the exact values that "crntRecord" array contains?

Comment: Don't know which type `crntRecord` is. If it is a `DataRow`, `crntRecord[0]` would be of type `object` which very likely might be a `string`.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of what the values in the `crntRecord` array are?

Comment: Have you debugged your program and checked the values of `crntRecord` at indices 0, 1, 3, and 4?  I'd guess that at least one of those non-numeric.

Comment: I would venture to guess that the type returned by `crntRecord[3]` and `crntRecord[4]` are `String`.  You can confirm this by adding: `string test = crntRecord[3]` and checking to see if it compiles.

Comment: @CodingGorilla @Kundan Singh Chouhan yes they are the string type values but when i convert them to decimal i get the error `input string was not in the correct format

Comment: can you paste here what the string value is..? so that we can see

Comment: @John I'm going to go out on a limb and say that they're not actually decimal values... =)

Comment: @CodingGorilla i have edited the original post

Comment: are those "\" being passed..? you need to strip out the return characters if this is the case.. you can't convert a return char + "\43.445\" into a decimal ..of course it will fail ..try using string.replace() on each string or do a Check on the string if it contains "\" use String.Replace() else Convert the String into a Decimal

Comment: @DJKRAZE It's not a "\", it's a quotation mark. The \ is an escape character.

Comment: Daniel I can't tell looking at this small screen shot..

Comment: The values are surrounded by double quotes ("), that's why you get the error with `decimal.Parse()`

Comment: @CodingGorilla tnx for pointing me in the right dir

Comment: tnx everybody for taking the time..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `crntRecord` is an array of strings, you need to parse the strings to a decimal first.

Ex:

```
nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@num3"].Value = decimal.Parse(crntRecord[3].ToString());
```

Note that this will throw an exception if `crntRecord[3]` is not parseable to a decimal; if that's a situation that could occur, look into `decimal.TryParse()` instead.

Comment: i get the exception `Input string was not in a correct format.`

Comment: @John Then it's not a value parseable to a decimal. What *is* the value?

Comment: you are right it does not look like a string can you please have a look at the edit i made to the original post

Comment: Your value is `"-71.013202"`, with quotation marks. Try `decimal.Parse(crntRecord[3].ToString().Replace("\"", string.Empty));`

Answer (score 3):

**Edited to use safer parsing methods**

Your strings have surrounding quotes that you need to strip off.  Try

```
decimal num3;
bool isDecimal = decimal.TryParse(crntRecord[3].Trim(new []{'\"'}), out num3);
if(isDecimal)
    nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@num3"].Value = num3;
```

I would recommend using this method for all of your decimals, which would mean putting this logic in a reusable function would be a rise refactoring.

Comment: The caveat to this answer is that obviously whatever it is that's providing the values to crntRecord is not restrained to providing valid decimal values.  So I would strongly suggest that instead of doing the Convert call in-line that you instead use `Decimal.TryParse()` and handle the case where the value is not really a decimal value.

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@num1"].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(crntRecord[0]));
nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@num2"].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(crntRecord[1]);
nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@num3"].Value =Convert.ToDecimal(crntRecord[3]);
nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@num4"].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(crntRecord[4]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
nonqueryCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num1", crntRecord[0]);
```

Comment: notice that the expected Param is a Decimal there needs to be a conversion done or use the internal .Parse functionality..

Comment: AddWithValue can convert many objects for us acepting that c# variables are way diferent from any DB variables. there was no need to give my answer a down vote.

Comment: `AddWithValue` will definitely create a parameter of an appropriate `SqlDbType` for the .NET type that `crntRecord[0]` is. The problem you have is that the OP specifically needs a **`SqlDbType.Decimal`** parameter. Suppose `crntRecord[0]` was a string with a value of `"ThisIsAString"`. Calling `AddWithValue` will result in `SqlDbType.SqlString` parameter, which will then fail when the query hits the DB.

Comment: `AddWithValue` is great when your objects match up to the appropriate data types that your query is expecting.  It does not work well if you need to convert your object first (as is the case when you have a string representation of a numeric type).

Comment: MalGani in order to prove if it's right or wrong try testing it yourself and seeing if your theory holds if so I am sure someone will change your downvote to an upvote